# Проблема с подключением БД на MYSQL C# WPF (запрещается удаленный доступ)

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, hosting

В общем такая ситуация, пишу программу, которая должна подключаться к базе данных, но возникла одна очень глобальная проблема с подключением клиента к базе. На хостинге стоит защита, то есть доступ к базе выдается только на определенные IP, которые я могу настроить там, но ведь у каждого другого юзера данной программы она не будет работать, ведь его IP нету в вайтлисте хостинга для подключения удаленно. [image: картинка]

Единственное, что я знаю по хостингу, порт - 3306
Хостинг ничего не может сказать.
я не знаю, как мне в данный момент реализовать программу, у меня нету большого опыта в работе с базой даннных, тем более с mysql в wpf. Буду очень благодарен если кто то поможет, мне нужно в максимальные сроки уже закончить разработку и доделать приложение

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF). основная мысль: вы задумали что-то неправильное. потому что удалённый доступ к базе данных — это очень плохой выбор.